# Backend - Created item not showing value in Grid

Tags: admin, backend, grid

Edit: I found the mistake. I'll mark answer as soon as I can (2 day's waiting time)

Hope the titel is clear enough...
I made a small backend module created with 'Magento UMC'. In one of my Tabs I added a dropdown field with a dummy value which I planned to swap with a collection of all Attribute titles. I actually managed to get that done and I also modified the following file so the right value gets saved in the database:

```
<?php


class MP_Search_Model_Element_Attribute_Source_Attribute extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
{


    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
    {
        $options = array();
        $attributeCollection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                                ->getAttributeCollection();

        foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribtue) {
            array_push($options,
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('mp_search')->__($attribtue->getName()),
                    'value' => $attribtue->getId()
                )
            );
        }

        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        }

        return $options;
    }


    public function getOptionsArray($withEmpty = true)
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions($withEmpty) as $option) {
            $options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
        return $options;
    }


    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getOptionsArray();
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $value = explode(',', $value);
        }
        $texts = array();
        foreach ($value as $v) {
            if (isset($options[$v])) {
                $texts[] = $options[$v];
            }
        }
        return implode(', ', $texts);
    }
}
```

I only changed the `getAllOtions()` method. This is how the original looked:

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
{
    $options =  array(
        array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mp_search')->__('All Attributes'),
            'value' => 1
        ),
    );
    if ($withEmpty) {
        array_unshift($options, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
    }
    return $options;

}
```

I changed the `$fieldset->addField()` in the /Tab/Form.php to show all Attributes in the dropdown menu:

```
class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Element_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $attributeCollection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                                ->getAttributeCollection();

        $attributes = array();
        foreach($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
            array_push($attributes, $attribute->getName());
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'attribute',
            'select',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('mp_search')->__('Attribute'),
                'name'  => 'attribute',
            'note'  => $this->__('Choose Attribute'),
            'required'  => true,
            'class' => 'required-entry',

            'values'=> $attributes,
           )
        );
```

I left the Grid.php untouched since all Attributes are shown in the dropdown field. But if I create an item with an Attribute, for example color, the attribute name doesn't appear in the Grid. If I set the attribute filter to 'color' the item also doesn't get shown. So I'm probably missing something here. I checked all the files but I can't tell which one is responsible for this. If more detail is required please tell me, I didn't wanted to post to much at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

```
class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Element_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $attributeCollection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                                ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                                ->getAttributeCollection();

        $attributes = array();
        foreach($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
            //array_push($attributes, $attribute->getName());
            $attributes[$attribute->getId()] = $attribute->getName();
        }
```

I had an array_push in there but I need the attribute Id as index.